# Is there way to preload all images in PDF document

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, images

I've prepared a quite image heavy presentation in InDesign, just to occur a bit annoying problem. After exporting interactive PDF, and opening the file, some of the images and elements load on the run (but you can tell it's because of images).

Is there way to preload all images in PDF document, after opening just first page?

Comment: This is better asked on stackoverflow but im pretty sure the answer is: No.

Comment: Are you viewing the document locally in Acrobat/Reader, or are you viewing it in a webbrowser?

Comment: I'm using Acrobat/Reader.